# Cancel GetObjectRequest Amazon S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I download an image from S3 using their SDK as follows:

```
s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("a24images", s3FileURLString), file);
```

However, I can't find anything in the docs to indicate how to:

• cancel a request
• pause a request

Any advice on implementing cancel and pause on these requests would be appreciated please.

Comment: how did you cancelled the request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the:

```
 S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketname, key));
```

will give you a handler to the object. You would further need to read the object to either a file system or an output stream like this:

```
    InputStream is = object.getObjectContent();
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[BYTES_DOWNLOAD];
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        os.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
```

The while loop above will actually read the object from S3 and in this case convert it to an OutputStream.

You may want to look at controlling the while loop with a boolean value that you can set from wherever you need to cancel this request.

Is this what you need to achieve ?
Or have I got the question wrong ?

This answer is in terms with the java sdk.

Thanks

Comment: The line of code I provided directly downloads the file to disk - I assume that Amazon has optimised that process so I do not want to overwrite it with my own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The variant of the `getObject` method you are using may not allow for cancellation, but if you just use the more basic `s3Client.getObject(
                  new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));` then this should just give you a reference to an input stream as already mentioned by sanket.

There is not really much "optimization" being done here, but if you wanted to see or reuse the code that Amazon itself uses it's here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/internal/ServiceUtils.java?source=c#L236

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
myS3Client.shutdown();
```

but i did manual tracking i just take one Boolean and when user try to cancel then it will be false and the time when download from s3 just check weather it is true or false if false then i delete that file from my side in sdcard.

Comment: I just want to cancel a request, not shutdown the Client

Comment: ya then use multipart download instead of getobject request i try for same but cant get success then i use manual tracking :)